# Answers that handle a different case of a general error message

Tags: discussion, answers

From time to time I come across questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x):  the OP has triggered an error message which could have many different causes.  The OP provides sufficient information in the question for the exact cause to be identified in the answers.

Over time the question accrues answers which identify *other* possible causes of the error message, along the lines of

> I got *error message* too and fixed it by *fixing the different specific problem that triggered the message in my case*

What, if anything,  should be done about these answers?

- **flag as NAA (me too):** this doesn't seem right, as they are answers, just to a slightly different question
- **downvote:** again this doesn't seem right, as the answers could be useful to another user encountering the same error message
- **nothing:** the answers are helpful to users who arrive at the answer through searching for the error message
- **upvote:** the answers could be useful to another user encountering the same error message

Comment: *as the answers could be useful to another user encountering the same error message* - that's the key. Consider putting upvoting on the list of things you may do.

Comment: One thing that could be done is to fix the normal words in code formatting... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search is a mystery - one would never know what way of asking question eventually will become "the answer"... Since we want answers to "the same question" to be in one place I think this is fine to have multiple answers why one can see the error message in the same post.

Overall we want questions to be on-topic, easy to find by search and easy to identify if you have the same problem or not. To achieve that:

- check if question is actually on-topic and not too broad. Look for a better duplicates and close/vote as duplicate, consider if merging is needed in this case or comment for authors of answers to move they posts to duplicate. Something like "why I'm getting 'missing semicolon' error" will be too broad if one try to expand it by removing code sample by editing the question (and probably question should be closed as "typographical error").
- then see if editing can help with identify part - clearly specified conditions, easy to read minimal code, generally nicely formatted
- finally see if question can be either expanded by editing to be more  canonical question on the particular error message but stay scoped enough.

Notes
- question needs to stay specific enough to be on-topic. You can look at [NRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?page=1&tab=votes) as probably the broadest acceptable question of this kind. 
- If you plan to do big edit of the question/ask to merge or move answers it may be good idea to start discussion on Meta first to make sure that you pick the best question as canonical and in general get more specific advice.